# Python panda: How to modify dataframe with multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to modify dataframe with multiple values to have single values

Original input with multiple items/value

```
    category       item
0      vowel  A E I O U
1  consonant          B
2  consonant          C
3     number          1
4     number          2
5        mix      2a Z6
```

Expected modified dataframe

```
     category item
0       vowel    A
1       vowel    E
2       vowel    I
3       vowel    O
4       vowel    U
5   consonant    B
6   consonant    C
7      number    1
8      number    2
9         mix   2a
10        mix   Z6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with splitted values by whitespaces by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = df.assign(item = df['item'].str.split()).explode('item').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     category item
0       vowel    A
1       vowel    E
2       vowel    I
3       vowel    O
4       vowel    U
5   consonant    B
6   consonant    C
7      number    1
8      number    2
9         mix   2a
10        mix   Z6
```

Comment: Thanks it works. By the way, when I got the numbers as NaN, [ 7      number  NaN
8      number  NaN ].  Anything need to set?